# Excel 2010 - Copying filtered results to new sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm struggling with M$ Excel trying to create a formula to copy results over to another sheet. I think I may need to VBA it.

I have three sheets. One called **Pupils**, one called **Days** and the other, **Timetable**.

**Pupils** column A is "*Name*" and column B is a drop down list "*Day*" with days off the week as options.

I'm trying to create a formula that looks at column B and determines what day has been chosen then copies the pupils name from column A (*Name*) into sheet **Timetable** column A; row 1, 2, 3, etc.

Is this possible?

I've got this in my **Timetable** sheet

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(Pupils!$G$2:$G$663,Days!$C$2)),"true","false")
```

but this only checks if the results are true, which they are.

Do my ramblings make sense?

Thanx for looking.

Sam

Comment: Does each row in `Timetable` refer to a different date? What does the formula you posted mean in relation to putting the date in `Timetable`?  It would help to see some sample data with the expected output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're intent to use VBA, a simple approach is to just copy everything over, then do the evaluation on sheets("Timetable") .

```
Dim i as integer
Dim LR as Long

LR = Sheets("Pupils).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Pupils").Range("A1:B"&LR).Copy Sheets("Timetable").Range("A1:B"&LR)

For i = LR to 2 Step -1
    If Sheets("Timetable").Cells(i,2).Value=Sheets(Pupils).Cells(2,2).Value Then
    Else: Sheets("Timetable").Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

I went the route of using an if statement, where if your day in column B matches the Pupils tab cell B2, then nothing happens, but if it doesn't match, it deletes the row.  Note that the For loop has a negative step, since the last row is defined BEFORE you start deleting, so you want to go backwards from the bottom to top.

Edit:

If you want to make a cell on Sheets("Timetable") say the date, you could change the If statement to reflect that cell, e.g.

```
=Sheets("Timetable").Cells(1,3) 'if you have the drop-down table in C1
```

You could also make a Userform to select the day of the week, if you really want to dig into it.  You would save the input as a variable and compare similar to:

```
Dim DayInput as String

DayInput=CheckBox1.Value

If Sheets("Timetable").Cells(i,2).Value=DayInput Then
```

Comment: This is the route I've chosen.

I've amended the code a little and output to a new sheet:
`code`Sub run_me()

Dim i As Integer
Dim LR As Long

LR = Sheets("Pupils").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Pupils").Range("B1:G700" & LR).Copy Sheets("Output").Range("A1:C20" & LR)

For i = LR To 2 Step -1
    If Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Pupils").Cells(2, 2).Value Then
    Else:
    Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub`code`

Would there be a way to limit the output of days, say five of each day?

Comment: Couple things... 1) If you're using set ranges, e.g. B1:G700, you don't need LR.  LR is used to dynamically define the last row.  2) If you're looking to only have 5 outputs for a given variable, you will need to go back through and either loop and remove rows after 5, or use .FIND.  You can look up the .FIND info, as there is a LOT out there.  Glad this worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

In an unused cell in the Timetable worksheet, put this formula,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Pupils!A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$1:A$99)/(Pupils!B$1:B$99=Days!$C$2), ROW(1:1))), TEXT(,))
```

Fill down. Adjust the `$99` portion if you have pupils listed in the Pupils worksheet below row 99.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could attach a file. I took part of Jeeped suggested formula.

In Timetable I set up 7 columns: Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat

In Timetable cell A2: =IF(Pupils!$B$2:$B$99=Days!$A$1,Pupils!$A2,"")

In Timetable cell B2: =IF(Pupils!$B$2:$B$99=Days!$A$2,Pupils!$A2,"")

... continue across for all 7 columns, note the edit of the Days cell reference

... then pull all 7 columns down for as many rows as there are pupils

In Timetable cell A3: =IF(Pupils!$B$2:$B$99=Days!$A$1,Pupils!$A3,"")

In Timetable cell A4: =IF(Pupils!$B$2:$B$99=Days!$A$1,Pupils!$A4,"")

...

Hope this is what you wanted for a 'timetable'.